# Visual aspect of website

Tags: html, css

I am new to web design, and am struggling to get my head around the design aspect.
Let me be more specific in my question...do most people make their websites look attractive, with 3d boxes, shadow effects, textured backgrounds etc with CSS entirely? Obviously photo editing would be done elsewhere but being new to CSS it is hard to see how it could be as powerful as using a piece of software.

For example - the website below...would the main nav bar at the top (with a different texture to the background), , the actual background and  the box with Online 3d kit builder etc all be designed using CSS or do designers tend to create those types of objects elsewhere and just reference them as images in CSS code?

And referring to the images just below the main picture, would they have the link bar put on them with CSS or in another programme?

I realise all people do things differently, but I would really appreciate people's views/exeriences.

Link - http://www.mkksports.co.uk/

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be better suited for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: css is a "piece of software" - and it is powerful as far as its intended purpose goes. Typically you use a combination of css and intelligently crafted graphics. Once you are well versed in css you will know when to use which. Just dive in and you'll see.

Comment: "Do most people.."  On the web, I don't think you can find a true consensus around design.  I've seen sites use a single large image that text is tossed on; I've seen others that have exactly 2 images and everything else is CSS and everything in between.  Our primary admin site only has a single image in it and most everyone comments how great it looks.  There are numerous reasons for doing things in CSS instead of images.  Any reasonably good looking image is going to be at least 100+ KB.  A solid CSS file on the other hand is probably 10kb or less.  Which do you want to serve all day long?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the backgrounds and logo are made elsewhere and referenced by the CSS. The buttons in the header (including their orange button look on hover) are pure css. The teaser images' ("UNI SHOP", "BESPOKE SERVICES, etc.)  overlay text and formatting are pure css.

The idea: if you can do it in CSS, do. It makes it much easier to change the whole site at once, and keep it consistent. For example, you wouldn't need the same designer's original photoshop file to make a completely new teaser image. Just wrap the new image in the right class, copying the markup, and you've got a new identically-styled teaser with the exact same formatting effect.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use CSS for styling whenever possible. CSS loads much faster and uses less bandwidth than loading a bunch of images. Any time you can use CSS to get the same effect as you could with a graphic design program, you should.

With CSS3 and HTML5 it's quite easy to accomplish a lot of the looks that used to require images.

That being said, the site you referenced is using background images for the navigation/page background, but they are using CSS for the hover effect on the links in the menu.